# The vector space $L^1$ is complete in its metric

Tags: real-analysis

> Theorem 2.2 (Riesz-Fischer) The vector space $L^1$ is complete in its metric
>   Consider a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty \,$ of $\{f_n\}$ with the following property:$$\Vert f_{n_{k+1}} - f_{n_k}\Vert_1 \leq \frac{1}{2^{k}}$$
>   Then consider the series whose convergence will be seen below, 
>   $$f = f_{n_1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (f_{n_{k+1}}-f_{n_k})$$and
>   $$g= \vert f_{n_1} \vert+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \vert f_{n_{k+1}}-f_{n_k} \vert$$
>   So the monotone convergence theorem implies that $g$ is integrable , and since $\vert f \vert \le g$  , hence so is $f$.

By the monotone convergence theorem , I can show $g$ is integerable, and $\vert f \vert \le g$ can be proved directly.However,since I can not prove $f_{n_k}$ converges to $f$ a.e. at this step.How to prove $f$ is integrable.Or how to show that $f$ is measurable. And how to prove the same conclusion in $L^2$ space, $\vert f \vert ^2 $ is measurable.

Comment: $f$ is measurable because countable sums of measurable functions is measurable.